# How to pass array as arg in Pipe in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have created a Pipe which purpose is to filter a list depending on a list of tags.

```
@Pipe({
  name: "tagfilter"
})
export class TagFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: Event[], args: any[]) :any {
    if (args.length === 0) {
      return items;
    }
    return _.filter(items, (item: any) => {
            return (_.intersection(item.tags, args[0]).length > 0)
        });
    }
}
```

I am then using it like this :

```
<tbody class="myline" *ngFor="#event of chapter.events | tagfilter:selectedTags" [event]="event">
```

However, "selectedTags" is an array of strings and if I add or remove entries from this array, it does not trigger the filter and so, my list is not filtered :/

Comment: try: `pipeName:arg1:arg2`

Comment: so: `tagFiler:items:args`

Comment: Yes but my array is dynamic and is constructed with checkboxes so I don't know the size of the array

Comment: why do you want to size it?

Comment: The pipe is trigger when items change, but not when selectedTags content changes.

Comment: you are only sending one argument to your pipe, so its going to be considered the items, not the args (which is considered the second arg)

Comment: The first arg of transform(list, arg) is the list before the pipe (here chapter.events). I have my selectedTags array in arg[0]

Comment: nvm I got you, the left hand of the pipe is the first argument right? uhmm....

Comment: The first parameter of transform is the value before the pipe (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) :) I don't have to specify it, it is automatically injected

Comment: From the docs: "Stateless pipes are pure functions that flow input data through without remembering anything or causing detectable side-effects." you need to make an `AsyncPipe` if you want it to detect further changes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that it's how change detection works in Angular2. I mean updates within objects don't trigger change detection but if you update the whole reference, it does.

To reevaluate the pipe, you need to replace the array with a new one:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app', 
  template: `
    <div>
      <span *ngFor="#l of (list | sort:excluded)">{{l}}</span>
    </div>
    <div (click)="updateArgs()">Update args</div>
  `,
  pipes: [ SortPipe ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.list = [ 'n', 'g', 'a', 'u', 'r', 'l' ];
  }

  updateArgs(array) {
    this.excluded = [ 'n', 'g' ];
  }
}
```

In my sample, when executing `updateArgs`, the `transform` method of the pipe is called again.

Here is a plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/GWcEOeY0koXZ5vroRntV?p=preview.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Yes, this works :) However, I would have liked not to have to reassign the array but just play with push() and splice() ^^

Comment: Yes, I know. Here is the answer from the Angular team regarding this behavior: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6458.