# how to get data from service in angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am able to get data using http (in a same component ) .But I am not getting data using service.can we call service method and grt data from server and display on component ?
I try to make service and try to get data from server .But I am not able to know how to use this service ?
http://plnkr.co/edit/hfhY6EdLVNOLP6d4QsWP?p=preview

```
import {Component, Injectable,Input,Output,EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core'
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
// Name Service
export interface myData {
   name:Array;
}



@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  sharingData: myData=[{name:"nyks"}];
   constructor(private http:Http) {
    }
  getData:Array()
  {
    this.sharingData.name=this.http.get('data.json')
        .map(res => res.json());

    return this.sharingData.name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
import {SharedService} from './service';

@Component({
  (...)
  providers: [SharedService]
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private service:SharedService) {
    this.service.getData();
  }
}
```

That said, I see strange things into your service since the Angular2 HTTP support leverages observables (asynchronous processing). I would refactor it this way:

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  //sharingData: myData=[{name:"nyks"}];
  constructor(private http:Http) {
  }

  getData:Array() {
    return this.http.get('data.json')
               .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

and in the component:

```
import {SharedService} from './service';

@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="d of dataToDisplay">{{d.name}}</li>
    <ul>
  `,
  providers: [SharedService]
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private service:SharedService) {
    this.service.getData().subscribe(data => {
      this.dataToDisplay = data;
    });
  }
}
```

This answer could give you more details:

- [How to Consume Http Component efficiently in a service in angular 2 beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450131/how-to-consume-http-component-efficiently-in-a-service-in-angular-2-beta/34450948#34450948)

Comment: wait sorry I will try wait

Comment: Yes sure! No worries!

Comment: I got your answer ...But my code is still work when i used sharingData variable http://plnkr.co/edit/hfhY6EdLVNOLP6d4QsWP?p=preview

Comment: Yes, but I'm pretty sure that the `sharingData` variable isn't what you expect it is ;-) It contains an observable not the data. The observable is responsible  to receive data when they will be received. If you want to share this observable, that's fine but I don't think it's what you try to do...

Comment: If you want to store received data as well in your service when received. You should do it when calling the `map` operator...

Comment: ok thanks ..could you please tell me how I will filter my data ..if I type anything in input field like auto complete in angular 1 I used pipe symbol ..here is my code  http://plnkr.co/edit/hfhY6EdLVNOLP6d4QsWP?p=preview

Comment: There is support of pipes (what is called filter in angular1). You can implement your own one. You can have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065668/how-to-pass-array-as-arg-in-pipe-in-angular2

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `SharedService` to the list of providers in bootstrap

```
bootstrap(MainComponent,[
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}),
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  SharedService
]);
```

then you can inject it into your component

```
export class MainComponent {
    constructor(private sharedService:SharedService) {}

    clickHandler() {
      this.data = sharedService.getData()
    }
}
```

the getData method needs to be fixed

```
 {
    this.sharingData.name=this.http.get('data.json')
        .map(res => res.json());
    // the following line is executed before the result arrives
    // because above code is async
    // therefore this always returns null
    return this.sharingData.name;
  }
```